# neural cryptography in C#

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, neural-network

Hello Dears
I'm developing a communication protocol to secure data transfer 
over a tcp network.
I want to use neural networks to e change the keys.
I found a protocol specification in wikipedia :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_cryptography#Tree_parity_machine
and an implementation in Delphi :
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/Neural_Cryptography1.aspx
and recently A new project in F# :
http://neuralcryptography.codeplex.com
I tried to implement it n C#
using aforge But I think it does not have some necessary features to implement a neural cryptography protocol
Can you help me to implement it in C#?
Thanks

Comment: Why neural crypto? Just for fun, or do you want to actually use it to secure data?

Comment: In short, no.  StackOverflow can help you with specific problems you're having, or specific questions you have, but it's not a place for people to write your code for you.  How far did you get with your C# implementation, and what are you stuck with?

Comment: Given the unproven nature of using neural networks in cryptography, I suspect that such an approach would be relying heavily on "security through obscurity". Unless you're working on a research paper, I would advise against such an approach.

Comment: See Dan's answer. The ideal starting point would be the F# project, given that it targets the CLR. With what code lines in the F# code are you stuck?

Answer (score 4):

Neural Cryptography (as in the links you posted) is crypto-analysis - using genetic algorithms rather than brute force to search a key space.  It seems to be the *reverse* of what you are wanting to build.

Additionally, to quote your wikipedia article:

> As of yet there no practical applications